# hot to access username present in login.html to index.js in node.js

Tags: html, node.js, mongodb

i am accessing the username field from the login.html file present in public folder to index.js file which is outside of public folder.

here is my login.html code which is in public folder

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>login</title>
</head>
<body>
 <h2> login to chat application </h2>
 <form method = "post"  action='/user'>
 <div class="container">
<label><b>Username</b></label>
<input type="text" id="username" placeholder="Enter Username" name="name" >
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</div>
</div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

here is my index.js file which is outside of public folder and i a accessing through route /user.

```
 var express = require('express');
 var socket = require('socket.io');
 var mongoose = require('mongoose');
 var app = express();
 var dbPath  = "mongodb://localhost/chat";
 // command to connect with database
 db = mongoose.connect(dbPath);
 mongoose.connection.once('open', function() {
 console.log("database connection open success");
 });

 var server = app.listen(8000,function(){
 console.log("The server is listening on the port 8000");
 });

 app.use(express.static('public'));
 app.get('/user', function(req,res){
  res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/login.html');
 })

 app.post('/user', function(req,res){
  if(req.body.name === undefined){
    console.log("user not found");
 }
  else{
    console.log("upto here")
    res.sendFile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
 }
})

var io = socket(server);
io.on('connection', function(socket){
socket.on("chat", function(data){
    io.sockets.emit("chat", data);
});

socket.on("typing", function (data){    
    socket.broadcast.emit("typing", data);
});
});
```

i have chat application accesing username from frontend page and using it to the chat file.

here i am unable to accessing the name="username" field to req.body.username please rectify me.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the `body-parser` package : https://www.npmjs.com/package/body-parser

```
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
```